# Dockerhub image pull error due to image registry unavailable

Tags: dockerhub

I cannot pull hello world image and other images just after 15:00 CST today but can do that yesterday and this morning CST.

- $docker pull hello-world
- Using default tag: latest 
  Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fhello-world%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

May I know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It is working now... 
- $ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
0e03bdcc26d7: Pull complete

Not sure what happened.